How do I fix an issue where 2 sites are live on the same domain from different hosts?
The company I work for recently decided to revamp our website which was created over 10 years ago.
We migrated our domain over from cPanel to Hostinger and began work on the new site. Everything was going well.
Earlier in the week we canceled our subscription with cPanel, however the old site is still up. Whenever customers click on our site they are redirected to the old site after we canceled cPanel.
We contacted the company that hosted our cPanel site for assistance however they stated we should contact Hostinger.
Hostinger tried to find this issue on their end but no luck. The site works completely fine on their side.
We are unsure now of what to do.
The old site was created using WordPress but the email linked to it has been deactivated for many years.
Could anyone advise us on how to proceed?

what is the domain ? check website is correctly pointed to Hostinger IP address or correct nameservers added.  Furthermore, Check website by connecting to VPN

The domain is blasmatics.co.za. When I search blasmatics on Google and click on the web link. It takes me to https://www.blasmatics.co.za/index.html

I checked the IP addresses and names servers, all are correct.

If I use incognito mode and access the site, it works fine

You have to clarify few things here first , is the new website on different domain or same domain ? , If the domain is same and has been pointed to new server please check if A records are transferred and name servers .
Check if there is cloudflare involved and nameservers or A address is pointing to that for caching purposes
I hope this will help

The new website is on the same domain.

How can I check to make sure the A records are correct??

You can find A record from hostinger or ask support they can give you . Once you have it check it in your domain provider if you have correct A record there and not the old one .

I've checked the A records and they match. I'm still having this issue unfortunately
